# height of div to adapt on screen

Tags: html, css

My navigation panel currently has the following attributes:

```
<div id='navpanel' 
     style='float:left; width:300px; height:100%; overflow:hidden;
     background:URL(assets/img/bg_tr.png);'>
```

However as you can see in the screenshot below, the height does not fill out until the end of the screen. I have tried to switch to "auto" however with the same result.

Does anybody have an idea how I can get the height of my panel to go down until the end no matter what screen resolution I currently have? Some advice would be highly appreciated - thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AnsJy/1/

Comment: Dear William, thank you very much for the swift answer, I have seen to implement your suggestion however I am getting the same result as earlier.

Comment: Is the piece of code you posted inside any other elements? If so, can you show those too.

Comment: OKay - I got it to work now - thank you very much Mr. Rensselaer!